# What is the "$\circ$" symbol in Graph Theory

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, notation

I have come across the following formula in Graph Theory and am trying to decipher what it means.

> $f(x\circ y)=f(x)\circ f(y)$

It is fairly simple but I have received a number of conflicting definitions of the "$\circ$" symbol which is making it hard to interpret. In some cases people where using this to represent contraction, some to represent relation, etc.

The source can be found [here](https://www.whitman.edu/documents/Academics/Mathematics/2014/rodriglr.pdf) in Definition $1.3$.

Comment: It looks like the group operation

Comment: Please make us clear where exactly is the trouble? Many pages? in which page?

Comment: Here $\circ$ is any group operation - any operation satisfying Def 1.1.

Comment: At this point, it has nothing to do with graphs yet, just groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with mappings between groups as defined in Def. $1.1$ in the linked document. A group is a set $S$ equipped with an inner operation $\circ\colon S\times S\to S, (a,b)\mapsto a\circ b$ satisfying some axioms (the ones given in your document). One may write $(S,\circ)$ denoting which set we are dealing with and in particular which operation is used. Now consider a different set $T$ with an inner operation $\star$ also satisfying the given axioms, making $(T,\star)$ a group aswell.

One can immediately consider usual *set-functions* $f\colon S\to T$ assigning to each element $s\in S$ and element $t:=f(s)\in T$. What is defined in Def. $1.3$ is a so-called *group homomorphism*. This is nothing but a set-function between $S$ and $T$ preserving the structure given by the inner operations $\circ$ and $\star$, respectively. This presevation is given by the axiom $f(a\circ b)=f(a)\star f(b)$ $\forall a,b\in S$; it is equal to first computing $a\circ b$ and then applying the set-function $f$ or first applying the set-function $f$ to both elements and the computing $f(a)\star f(b)$. To put it different, it is not important which way we choose to go in the following diagram(s)

> $$\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
> S\times S @>{f\times f}>> T\times T\\
> @V{\circ}VV @VV{\star}V \\
> S @>>{f}> T
> \end{CD}~~\implies~~
> \begin{CD}
> (a,b) @>{f\times f}>> (f(a),f(b))\\
> @V{\circ}VV @VV{\star}V \\
> a\circ b @>>{f}> f(a\circ b)=f(a)\star f(b)
> \end{CD}$$

In the given case two groups are considered, $G$ and $G'$, where the operation is denoted by $\circ$ in both cases (this is a quite common abuse of notation, [as it was already discussed yesterday for example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3581290/convention-in-defining-a-group)). $f$ is a set-function $f\colon G\to G'$ such that $f(x\circ_G y)=f(x)\circ_{G'} f(y)$ (for emphasis I denoted $\circ$ accordingly, in constrast to the author's choice). Note, however, authors tend to not specify which operation is referred to leading to the axiom $f(x\circ y)=f(x)\circ f(y)$ $\forall x,y\in G$.

Comment: Breaking out the commutative diagrams sorta seems like overkill for helping someone who is only just learning what a group is.  IMHO.

Comment: @JairTaylor It might help to visualize things, but yeah, arguably it's a complete overkill.

Comment: I have to admit this is a bit over my head, but it is a perfect answer and gives me a lot of areas to do more research into so exactly what I was hoping for!

Comment: @JFreeman As soon as you stumble into new questions: ask them here on MSE! That's afterall the purpose of this site :)

Comment: @mrtaurho - coming back to your answer after doing more research it makes tonnes of sense and is incredibly helpful! So thank you again!

Comment: @JFreeman Glad to hear!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that $\circ$ is the group operation here.

In the homomorphism $f:G \to G^\prime$ between two groups, with $f(x\circ y) =f(x)\circ f(y)$,

- the first $\circ$ is the group operation for $G$ and
- the second $\circ$ is the group operation for $G^\prime$